Is there a method to load caseless models to Stanford's NLP sentiment analysis?
In the Stanford documentation, the authors mention using caseless models to process case-insensitive text. Namely the ability to load the GATE Twitter POS annotator. It is a POS annotator, but it doesn't mention that sentiment analysis processes this model to predict sentiment. How do I load it to CoreNLP and let the sentiment annotator use the more accurate models, not just for part-of-speech tagging?

Hi @Abdul M. Diaz , The Stanford caseless models are for Named Entity Recognition. Are you after NER or sentiment analysis?

Sentiment analysis @SidharthMacherla
